# Чтение словаря из файла в Python

Tags: python, словари

Есть файл text.txt, в которм лежит что-то наподобие:

```
{"a" : "1", "b" : "2"}
```

Tребуется прочитать этот файл в словарь `dict`. Kак это сделать?

Comment: Может быть, у вас в файле лежит JSON? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Нужно не «наподобие», а обозначить конкретный формат и конкретную его спецификацию со всеми правилами парсинга, иначе непонятно, как его вообще правильно читать. Быть может, у вас и в самом деле JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться стандартным модулем [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), в котором есть необходимая Вам [функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

***Пример:***

```py
import ast


def main():
    with open('text.txt') as f:
        text = f.read()

    d = ast.literal_eval(text)
    print(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```

Comment: Что из себя представляет модуль ast?

Comment: @SergoArkhipov [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). Стандартный модуль, который `Python` использует для создания различных объектов из строк.

Answer (score -1):

Функция `exec` выполняет код на питоне записанный в строку.

```
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    your_dict = exec(f.read())

print(your_dict)
```

Если в файле со словарем будет ошибка, то она исполнится и в программе.Чтобы это избежать можно cделать так:

```
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    try:
        your_dict = exec(f.read())
        print(your_dict)

    except:
        print("Error")
```

Comment: `f.close()` будет лишним, так как Вы используете контекстный менеджер `with`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 А он автоматически закрывает?

Comment: и избегает ошибки при чтении

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Да.

Comment: Минус за отсутствие пояснения функции `exec`. Не стоит просто так её кидать новичкам.

Comment: @Михаил Муругов Исправил.